# Doctrine Full outer join

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-query

I would like to do a full outer join in Doctrine ORM(PHP)

My current query is :

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Model_Contract_Payment p')
            ->innerJoin('p.Contract c')
            ->where(" c.modified_date IS NOT NULL AND (c.modified_date < '" . date(DATABASE_DATE_FORMAT, $lastShowableDate) . "' OR c.archive_status = 1 OR p.archive_status = 1)".$queryStr )
            ->orderBy($sortColumn . ' ' . $sortDirection);
```

If I do this way, I get only the contracts which has for contract_id and ignores the 
data with payment_id with NULL.

I would prefer to get all the data with payment_id NULL

So,I would like to replace the 
innerjoin with `FULL OUTER JOIN` .
Any idea on how to go about this?

My schema.yml file:

```
Contract:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: Contract
  columns:
    contract_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    hash:
      type: string(32)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    sales_force_opportunity_id:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    sales_force_opp_owner:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    sales_force_opp_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    sales_force_account_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contact_first_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contact_last_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contract_companyname:
      type: string(80)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contact_email_address:
      type: string(256)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contact_alternate_email_address:
      type: string(256)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contact_phone_number:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contract_status_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contract_agreed_ip_address:
      type: string(72)
      fixed: true
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    agreed_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    agreement_start_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    agreement_end_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    seat_details:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    special_instructions:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    agreement_type_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    agreement_terms:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    additional_terms:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    additional_notes:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_terms:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    total_value:
      type: decimal(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_method_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    bank_name:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    bank_account:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    bank_routing:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_short:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_encrypt:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_exp:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_type:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_first_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_last_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_address1:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_address2:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_city:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_state:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_country:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_postal_code:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_phone:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_first_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_last_name:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_address1:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_address2:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_city:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_state:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_country:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_postal_code:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    shipping_phone:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    rejection_notes:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    rvp_status_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    rvp_comment:
      type: string(2147483647)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    rvp_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_admin_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    modified_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    isenabled:
      type: boolean(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      default: 1
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    archive_status:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      default: 0
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contract_Status:
      local: contract_status_id
      foreign: contract_status_id
      type: one
    Agreement_Type:
      local: agreement_type_id
      foreign: agreement_type_id
      type: one
    Payment_Method:
      local: payment_method_id
      foreign: payment_method_id
      type: one
    AdminUser:
      local: created_admin_id
      foreign: admin_id
      type: one
    Contract_Payment:
      local: contract_id
      foreign: contract_id
      type: many
      cascade: [delete]
    Contract_Product:
      local: contract_id
      foreign: contract_id
      type: many
      cascade: [delete]
    Contract_Venue:
      local: contract_id
      foreign: contract_id
      type: many
      cascade: [delete]
Contract_Payment:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: Contract_Payment
  columns:
    payment_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    created_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    contract_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_status_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    amount:
      type: decimal(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_amount:
      type: decimal(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_amount1:
      type: decimal(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    check_amount:
      type: decimal(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    due_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    modified_date:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    modified_admin_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    notes:
      type: string(200)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_method_id:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_status_id_credit_card1:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    payment_status_id_credit_card2:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_holdername:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_short:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_encrypt:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_expiration:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_type:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    second_credit_card_enable:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_holdername1:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_short1:
      type: string(5)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_num_encrypt1:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_expiration1:
      type: timestamp(16)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    credit_card_type1:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    auth_reference:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    auth_reference1:
      type: string(100)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    billing_postal_code:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
    archive_status:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      notnull: true
      default: 0
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contract:
      local: contract_id
      foreign: contract_id
      type: one
    Payment_Status:
      local: payment_status_id
      foreign: payment_status_id
      type: one
    AdminUser:
      local: modified_admin_id
      foreign: admin_id
      type: one
    Contract_Payment_History:
      local: payment_id
      foreign: payment_id
      type: many
      cascade: [delete]
```

I am using SQL SERVER.
 Any idea would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood that full outer join is not possible in Doctrine ORM.
So, I have changed my application code to use the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Can you write as to the general strategy involved in altering OUTER JOIN to LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is missing some key info, it would be easier if you posted the SQL you wanted. But by the sounds of it you want to use `leftJoin` instead of `innerJoin` (LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN).

See [Coding Horror: A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for more information

Comment: I would like to implement a query like this:
`select p.*,c.* from
Contract c FULL OUTER JOIN ON(c.contract_id = p.contract_id)
WHERE  c.modified_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You using mysql? You can't have FULL OUTER JOIN. http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#690

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER
and full outer join is possible here.